# Python how to ignore or fix "IndexError: list index out of range"?

Tags: python, loops, range

So this result can have less than 10 answers at times. I am having a hard time figuring out how to ignore if 'overbought1' is less than 10. For example, if there are only 8 results I would like it to display 8 and ignore the last two that aren't there.

```
    try:
        for i in range(10):
            (runo[i])
    except:
        pass

    overbought1 = ("Top 10 overbought today: $" + runo[0] + " $" + runo[1] + " $" + runo[2] + " $" + runo[3] + " $" +runo[4] + " $" + runo[5] + " $" + runo[6] + " $" + runo[7]+ " $" + runo[8]+ " $" + runo[9])

    await client.say(overbought1)
```

Comment: `for i in range(len(runo)):` ?

Comment: What is `(runo[i])` supposed to be doing?

Comment: That whole try-except block does nothing and should be removed.  If you're trying to check if the length of `runo` is less than 10 or something, then do so directly with `len(runo)` and change the logic in `overbought`.

Answer (score 0):

While you entire example make little sense, here is one of the ways to avoid `IndexError`:

```
for i in range(min(10, len(runo))): # loop at most to the minimum
                                    # between ten and len(runo)
    (runo[i]) # <-- this does nothing here!
```

Another way:

```
for v in runo[:10]: # access no more than first 10 elements
    v # <-- also does nothing. v is equivalent to runo[i] from the previous loop
```

Now, if you want to fix your `overbought1` string, then do this:

```
overbought1 = "Top 10 overbought today: $" + " $".join(runo[:10])
```

or even:

```
overbought1 = ("Top %d overbought today: $" % len(runo)) + " $".join(runo[:10])
```